# Add Search Bar with Next , Previous and close Button to find the Text string in html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am creating an mobile based website with lot of paragraphs and text inside it and lot of divs.

The page is very long and it contains enormous amount of words in a single html page.
I would like to implement the search bar (If possible hidden and show a small bar when, pressed would slide the search box to index page), with input box, Next button, previous button and close button (which will again hide the search bar). Thus when user input any Text say " Dogs", It would search for "Dogs" in an entire page and will take user and scroll automatically when pressed Next or previous button when there are many entries found of searched string.

Similar to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in desktop Browser.

Is it possible?

Here is the example on index.html page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,text/html,charset=utf-8' >
</head>

<h1 style="text-align: left;"><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong><span style="color: #ff0000; text-decoration: underline;">Cell Biology and Genetics</span></strong></span></h1>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<h2><span style="color: #000080;">Cell Biology / Organells</span></h2>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>1) Amembranous cell organelle</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong><em>@Rajkumar N Mahesh are Close and Mutual</em></strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Explanation:</p>
<p><strong>R</strong>- Ribosome Smallest cell Organelle</p>
<p><strong>N</strong> - Nucleolus</p>
<p><strong>M</strong> - Microtubule, Micro filaments</p>
<p><strong>C</strong> - Centriole</p>
<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; -Chromosome</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Note:-</p>
<p><strong><em>☞</em></strong> <strong>Organellele structure without membrane</strong></p>
<p><strong><em>&nbsp; @ Manob Chor Never Come To my Room</em></strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Explanation</p>
<ul>
<li>M: Microfilament</li>
<li>C: Chromosome</li>
<li>N: Nuclelous</li>
<li>C: Centriold</li>
<li>tM: Microtuble</li>
<li>R: Ribosome</li>
</ul>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><u>2) Single Membrane</u></p>
<p><strong><em>&nbsp;@ Singal Gal Love Entimate Partner</em></strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Explanation:</p>
<p>--&gt; <strong>S</strong>phaerosomes</p>
<p>--&gt; <strong>G</strong>lyoxysomes</p>
<p>--&gt; <strong>G</strong>olgi body</p>
<p>--&gt; <strong>Ly</strong>sosomes - small cell orgomelle with</p>
<p>--&gt; <strong>E.</strong>R membrane</p>
<p>--&gt; <strong>P</strong>eroxizome</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong>3) &nbsp;Organelle structure with double membrane</strong></p>
<p><strong><em>@ Double Prime Minister of Nepal</em></strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Explanation</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Double membrane</p>
<p>P: Plastid</p>
<p>M: Mitochondria</p>
<p>N: Nucleus</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Note:-</p>
<p><strong><em>☞</em></strong><strong><em> &nbsp;</em></strong>Organelle bounded by Triple membrane</p>
<p><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; T</strong>ransosome - <strong>T</strong>riple membrane <strong><em>( @ T for T)</em></strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong>4) Models of cell membrane</strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>i. Lipid model: proposed by overton</p>
<p><strong><em>@(Lipid &asymp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Fat ( </em></strong><strong><em>बोशो</em></strong><strong><em> )&nbsp; </em></strong><strong><em>धेरै</em></strong> <strong><em>भएपछि</em></strong> <strong><em>weight Over </em></strong><strong><em>भएर</em></strong> <strong><em>ton </em></strong><strong><em>मा</em></strong> <strong><em>mesaurable </em></strong><strong><em>हुन्छ</em></strong><strong><em>)</em></strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>ii. San<strong>D</strong>which model proposed by <strong>D</strong>anielli and <strong>D</strong>avson</p>
<p><strong>@D=D=D common</strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>iii. Fluid Mosaic mdel: Singer and Nicolson</p>
<p><strong><em>@(Fluid &asymp;&nbsp; Flute ( </em></strong><strong><em>बाशुरी</em></strong><strong><em> ) </em></strong><strong><em>जब</em></strong> <strong><em>flute </em></strong><strong><em>बज्छ</em></strong> <strong><em>तब</em></strong> <strong><em>Singer </em></strong><strong><em>ले</em></strong> <strong><em>गीत</em></strong> <strong><em>Nicalcha</em></strong> )</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong>5) &nbsp;Protoplasm </strong></p>
<p>i. <strong>D</strong>ujardin <strong>D</strong>iscovered protoplasm and term sarco<strong>D</strong>e</p>
<p><strong>@D is common</strong></p>
<p>ii. <strong>P</strong>urkinje coined the term <strong>p</strong>rotoplasm</p>
<p><strong>@P for P</strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong>6) Resolving power and magnification</strong></p>
<p><strong><em>@MERO </em></strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Explanation</p>
<p>i.e <strong>M</strong>agnification power depends upon the diameter of <strong>E</strong>ye lens and</p>
<p><strong>R</strong>esolving power depends upon the diameter of <strong>O</strong>bjective lens.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong>7) Mnemonic Device </strong></p>
<p><strong><em>@"BRIM GERL" </em></strong></p>
<p><strong><em>@"No Class Monday oR Friday"</em></strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong>Explanation</strong></p>
<p>Type of Ribosome and Protein Destination:</p>
<p>Bound Ribosome- Integral Membrane, Golgi, Endoplasmic Reticulum, and Lysosome.</p>
<p>Free Ribosome - Nucleus, Cytoplasm, and Mitochondria.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong>8) Mnemonic Device </strong></p>
<p><strong><em>@ "Golgi Distributes A SPAM"</em></strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong>Explanation</strong></p>
<p><u>Golgi complex: functions </u></p>
<p>Distributes proteins and lipids from ER:</p>
<p>Add mannose onto specific lysosome proteins</p>
<p>Sulfation of sugars and slected tyrosine</p>
<p>Proteoglycan assembly</p>
<p>Add O-oligosugars to serine and threnonine</p>
<p>Modify N-ologosugars on asparagine.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>...............................</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong><u>9) Shape of Chloroplast</u></strong></p>
<p><strong>&nbsp;<em>@ CC OR DV Z-Star </em></strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong>Explanation:- </strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong>C</strong>hlamydomonas = <strong>C</strong>upshaped</p>
<p><strong>O</strong>edogonium - <strong>R</strong>eticulate</p>
<p><strong>D</strong>isoid - <strong>V</strong>aucheria</p>
<p><strong>Z</strong>ygnema - <strong>S</strong>tar Shaped</p>
<p><strong>U</strong>lothrix - <strong>U</strong> shaped or girdle shapeorHorse shue shape</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>....................</p>
<h1>&nbsp;</h1>
<h1><span style="color: #000080;">Cell Cycle</span></h1>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong>1) Mneumonic Device</strong></p>
<p><em><strong>@!&ldquo;Go</strong></em>&nbsp;<em><strong>Sally</strong></em>&nbsp;<em><strong>Go!</strong></em>&nbsp;<em><strong>Make</strong></em>&nbsp;<em><strong>Children!&rdquo;</strong></em></p>
<p><em><strong>@&rdquo;Mahatma Gandhi Sonia Gandhi</strong></em></p>
<p><em><strong>Explanation:-</strong></em></p>
<p>Cell Cycle Can be divided into 2 stages:</p>
<p><strong>INTERPHASE:</strong></p>
<ul>
<li>G1&nbsp;Growth phase 1.</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>S&nbsp;Synthetic phase.</li>
<li>G2&nbsp;Growth phase2.</li>
</ul>
<p><strong>DIVISIONAL PHASE:</strong></p>
<ul>
<li>M&nbsp;Mitosis/Meiosis.</li>
<li><em>C</em>&nbsp;Cytokinesis.</li>
<li>&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
<p><strong>2) Mitosis</strong></p>
<p><em><strong>@&ldquo;People</strong></em>&nbsp;<em><strong>Meet</strong></em>&nbsp;<em><strong>And</strong></em>&nbsp;<em><strong>Talk (PMAT)&rdquo;</strong></em></p>
<ul>
<li><strong>Prophase,</strong></li>
<li><strong>Metaphase,</strong></li>
<li><strong>Anaphase,</strong></li>
<li><strong>Telophase.</strong></li>
</ul>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong>3)Meiosis</strong></p>
<p><em><strong>@&ldquo;PMAT X 2&rdquo;</strong></em></p>
<p>Explanation:-</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>It occurs in 2 stages:</p>
<p><strong><u>i)Meiosis</u></strong>&nbsp;<strong><em><u>I</u></em></strong>&nbsp;<strong><em>&ndash; reductional division:</em></strong></p>
<p>Prophase I,&nbsp;Metaphase I,&nbsp;Anaphase I,&nbsp;Telophase I.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong><u>ii)Meiosis II</u></strong>&nbsp;<strong><em>&ndash; equational division:</em></strong></p>
<p>Prophase II,&nbsp;Metaphase II,&nbsp;Anaphase II,&nbsp;Telophase II.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Note:-</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong><u>Prophase I</u></strong><strong><em>:</em></strong>&nbsp;divided into 5 substages:</p>
<p><em><strong>@Little</strong></em>&nbsp;<em><strong>Zara!&nbsp;Please&nbsp;Dance&nbsp;Daily.</strong></em></p>
<ul>
<li><strong>Leptotene,</strong></li>
<li><strong>Zygotene,</strong></li>
<li><strong>Pachytene,</strong></li>
<li><strong>Diplotene,</strong></li>
</ul>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<h2><span style="color: #000080;">Genetics</span></h2>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong>1)&nbsp; Term given by Bateson</strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong><em>@BAG </em></strong></p>
<p>Explanation</p>
<p><strong>B</strong>atteson term -<strong> A</strong>llelomorph / Allele</p>
<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; - <strong>G</strong>enetics</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong>B</strong>ateson term:&nbsp;&nbsp; <strong>A</strong>llelomorph or allele, <strong>G</strong>enetic</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><em>( Homozygous and heterozygous are also termed because allele is </em></p>
<p><em>determinant for it.)</em></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>2) Mnemonic Device</p>
<p><strong><em>&nbsp;(@Bateson is Genius MAn father)</em></strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Explanation</p>
<p>Bateson father of <strong>M</strong>odern <strong>gen</strong>etics</p>
<p>Father of <strong>An</strong>imal <strong>gen</strong>etics</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong>3)Mneumonic Device:</strong></p>
<p><strong><em>@Alphabetically r, s (m), t.</em></strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong>Explanation:</strong></p>
<p>RNA processing</p>
<p>In Eukaryotes, there are 3 RNA Polymerases.</p>
<p>RNA Polymerase I --&gt;&nbsp;rRNA.</p>
<p>RNA Polymerase II --&gt;&nbsp;mRNA.</p>
<p>RNA Polymerase III --&gt;&nbsp;tRNA.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Alphabetically&nbsp;r, s (m),&nbsp;t.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong>4) Prcoseing of RNA</strong></p>
<p><strong>Processing of RNA occurs in 3 steps:</strong></p>
<p><strong>1. SPLICING: REMOVAL OF INTRONS AND JOINING OF EXONS.</strong></p>
<p>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>EXons</strong>&nbsp;<strong>EXpressed,</strong>&nbsp;<strong>INtrons</strong>&nbsp;<strong>IN</strong>&nbsp;<strong>the trash.</strong></p>
<p><strong>2. CAPPING: ADDITION OF</strong>&nbsp;<em>METHYGUANOSINE PHOSPHATE</em>&nbsp;<strong>CAPS AT</strong>&nbsp;<em>5&prime;</em>&nbsp;<strong>END.</strong></p>
<p><strong>&nbsp;3. TAILING:</strong>&nbsp;<em>POLY-ADENYLATION</em>&nbsp;<strong>OCCURS AT</strong>&nbsp;<em>3&prime;</em>&nbsp;<strong>END.</strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>@<strong><em>Alphabetically and numerically</em></strong></p>
<p><strong><em>3 &amp; A&nbsp;comes first,</em></strong>&nbsp;<strong><em>so</em></strong>&nbsp;<strong><em>A at 3&prime;&nbsp;end.</em></strong></p>
<p><strong><em>5 &amp; G</em></strong>&nbsp;<strong><em>comes&nbsp;later so&nbsp;G at 5&prime;end.</em></strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong>Note:-</strong></p>
<p><strong>Eukaryotes have&nbsp;</strong><em>Split genes.</em></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>5) Mnemonic Device</p>
<p><strong><em>&nbsp;@ID Ma Anti </em></strong><strong><em>ले</em></strong> <strong><em>Anda </em></strong><strong><em>पकाउनुहुन्छ</em></strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Explanation</p>
<p><strong>ID</strong>: <strong>I</strong>ncomplete <strong>D</strong>ominance</p>
<p>Ma: Mirabilis Jalapa (4'0 clock plant )</p>
<p>Anti: Antirrhimum majus</p>
<p>Anda: Andalusian fowl</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>6) Codominance</p>
<p><strong><em>@CASCO </em></strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Explanation</p>
<p>C: Codominance</p>
<p>A: ABO blood goup</p>
<p>S: Sickle cell trait</p>
<p>CO: Coat colour</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>7) &nbsp;Mutation</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>i. X-rays causes mutation by Deletion</p>
<p><strong><em>(@X is sign of deletion)</em></strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>ii. UV-rays cause mutation by forming dimer</p>
<p><strong><em>(@ UV has 2 letter so cause mutation by dimer )</em></strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>iii) y-rays cause mutation by producing free radical C</p>
<p><strong><em>@ y is electromagnetic wave and neutral like ligh and light produce free radicle . </em></strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>8) &nbsp;Mnemonic Device</p>
<p><strong><em>&nbsp;@Mo Tu </em></strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Explanation</p>
<p>Monosomy condition ( 2n-1) gives Turner syndrome</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong>9) Initiation codon:</strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;Initiation codon&nbsp;on mRNA.</p>
<p><em><strong>AUG</strong></em>&nbsp;<em><strong>--&gt; INAUGURATES PROTEIN SYNTHESIS.</strong></em></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong>9) Termination codon name</strong></p>
<p>i. UAG: Amber</p>
<p>&nbsp;&nbsp; <strong><em>@ UAG &asymp; AAG&nbsp; Amber ( </em></strong><strong><em>आग</em></strong><strong><em>) </em></strong><strong><em>आगो</em></strong> <strong><em>भनेको</em></strong>&nbsp;&nbsp; <strong><em>Amber </em></strong><strong><em>संस्कृतमा</em></strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>ii. UGA: Opal</p>
<p><strong><em>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; @UGA &asymp;&nbsp; GopAL: Opal</em></strong></p>
<p>iii. UAA: Ochre (Muj up )</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><u>Note:-</u></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><u>Termination codons</u>&nbsp;on mRNA:</p>
<p><em><strong>UAA</strong></em>&nbsp;<em><strong>--&gt;</strong></em>&nbsp;<em><strong>U</strong></em>&nbsp;<em><strong>ARE</strong></em>&nbsp;<em><strong>AWAY.</strong></em></p>
<p><em><strong>UAG</strong></em>&nbsp;<em><strong>--&gt;</strong></em>&nbsp;<em><strong>U ARE</strong></em>&nbsp;<em><strong>GONE.</strong></em></p>
<p><em><strong>UGA</strong></em>&nbsp;<em><strong>--&gt; &nbsp;U</strong></em>&nbsp;<em><strong>GO</strong></em>&nbsp;<em><strong>AWAY.</strong></em></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong><u>10) PROTEIN</u></strong>&nbsp;<strong><u>SYNTHESIS</u></strong>&nbsp;</p>
<p>iT OCCURS WITH THE HELP OF RIBOSOMES. THEY&nbsp;</p>
<p>CONSIST OF 2 SUBUNITS :</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><em><strong>IN</strong></em>&nbsp;<em><strong>EUKARYOTES: 40S + 60S --&gt; 80S (EVEN)</strong></em>.</p>
<p><em><strong>IN</strong></em>&nbsp;<em><strong>PROKARYOTES: 30S + 50S --&gt; 70S (ODD</strong></em>).</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong>11) Ribosome</strong></p>
<p>A Ribosome has 3 sites:</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><em>A</em>&nbsp;<em>SITE = INCOMING</em>&nbsp;<em>AMINOACYL-TRNA.</em></p>
<p><em>P</em>&nbsp;<em>SITE = GROWING</em>&nbsp;<em>PEPTIDE CHAIN</em><em>.</em></p>
<p><em>E</em>&nbsp;<em>SITE = HOLDS</em>&nbsp;<em>EMPTY TRNA AS ITS</em>&nbsp;<em>EXITS</em><em>.</em></p>
<p><strong>Messenger RNA acts as the&nbsp;<em>template for protein synthesis.</em></strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>AMINO ACID ATTACHMENT ARM HAS A&nbsp;C C A SEQUENCE&nbsp;</p>
<p>BY THE HELP OF WHICH IT FORMS ESTER BOND WITH AMINO</p>
<p>ACID.</p>
<p><em><strong>C C A</strong></em>&nbsp;<em><strong>&ndash;</strong></em><strong>&nbsp;@</strong><em><strong>Can</strong></em>&nbsp;<em><strong>Carry</strong></em>&nbsp;<em><strong>Amino acid.</strong></em></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong>12) Mnemonic Device</strong></p>
<p><strong><em>@ Operaon concept is like MoJa</em></strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Explanation</p>
<p><strong>Operon concept</strong> given by <strong>Mo</strong>nad and <strong>Ja</strong>cob</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>13)Enzyme Classification</p>
<p><strong><em>&ldquo;Over The HILL&ldquo;</em></strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Explanation:</p>
<ul>
<li>Oxidoreductases</li>
<li>Transferases</li>
<li>Hydrolases</li>
<li>Isomerases</li>
<li>Ligases</li>
<li>Lyases</li>
</ul>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>14) Mnemonic Device</p>
<p><strong><em>@"The Rhythm Nearly Proved Contagious"</em></strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong>Explanation</strong></p>
<p>Vitamin 'B' names in increasing order:</p>
<ul>
<li>Thiamine (B1)</li>
<li>Riboflavin (B2)</li>
<li>Niacin (B3)</li>
<li>Pyridoxine (B6)</li>
<li>Cobalamin (B12)</li>
</ul>
<p>......................................................</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong>15) Mnemonic Device</strong></p>
<p><strong><em>@"PHenylketonuria"</em></strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong>Explanation</strong></p>
<p>Phenylketonuria: which enzyme is deficient</p>
<p>PHenylketonuria is caused by a deficiency of:</p>
<p>Phenylalanine Hydroxylase.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>


<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you already tried yourself to find the problem? Questions should show evidence of research and **attempts to solve the problem yourself**, a clear outline of your specific coding-related issue, and the *relevant* code in a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**, so we have enough information to be able to help.

Comment: @FluffyKitten , I think question is clear , right? No I searched for same but I didn't find any solution to specific problem so I have no idea ho to proceed and yes I haven't tried anything yet.

Comment: It is clear in your question what you *want* to do, but not what you have already tried yourself or any research you have done. That is required for questions on Stack Overflow - the site is for help you fix specific coding issues, not add whole functions for you. If you don't know how to proceed, then you either need to do more research to find out how, or hire a professional to do it for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add Search Bar with Next, Previous and close Button to search text in main html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46755535/how-to-add-search-bar-with-next-previous-and-close-button-to-search-text-in-mai)